# Regex - one pattern for three cases with / without minus character / without any number

Tags: regex

In our application it needs a pattern to validate three cases below:

1. "Any character" + "-" + "Any character" + "a number" `// ^([a-zA-Z]+)-([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)`
2. or "Any character" + "a number"  `// ^([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)`
3. or "Any character" (without any number at the end)

I couldn't make it run for the (3) condition and combine them into one pattern. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: I wonder if you are looking for something like this: [`^[a-zA-Z]+(?:(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)?[0-9]+|(?!.*[0-9]$).*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/aC6pE2/1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
^(?:([a-zA-Z]+)-)?([a-zA-Z]+([0-9]+))$|^([a-zA-Z]+)$
```

I got your first pattern.

I made the *"Any character" + "-"* optional so that it will work for the second case too.

I added an alternative for the third case - `|^([a-zA-Z]+)`.

---

A more readable version without unnecessary groups:

```
^(?:(?:[a-zA-Z]+-)?[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]+)$
```

Comment: Thanks @ndn for replying. But it seems that "ABCD123" is still being valid. so the condition 3rd is not OK

Comment: @fredho, shouldn't *"ABCD123"* be valid according to the second rule?

Comment: If I test "ABCD-123" it is still working. Maybe the pattern for 3rd condition should be updated.

Comment: @fredho, I added `$` so that the regex would try to match the entire string. Note that your initial regex wasn't protected from that either.

Comment: yes, the last one work. The first one doesn't work in this case "ABC-D123-1"

Comment: @fredho, what do you mean? Neither matches *"ABC-D123-1"* because there isn't a rule that says it should. Only the first rule mentions a dash and there is only one dash in that rule.

Comment: I mean the last pattern you provided "A more readable" fixes that case also. So two patterns are not equal :).  Thanks for your help !

Comment: Yes, I did. Finally this one work. "^(?:(?:[a-zA-Z]+-)?[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]+)$"